# How to attain virtualization in listbox with different layouts of Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, virtualization

I have a List box with different user controls in WP7 app. How should I apply virtualization with [Virtualization Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode.aspx) as "recycling". Because when I applied the results are not smooth. There seem to be a jerk while scrolling. In Android, for the same scenario the User Controls will be tagged their recycling is handled preoperly since they are perfectly distinguished and here any such option is not given.

Any idea how to handle this scenario?

I tagged silverlight and c# becuase WP7 has both sides when adding any such properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour you see is due to the items in the list being of different heights. This causes the list to constantly need to remeasure the contents and the scroll offsets become incorrect as items are removed from the list, hence the jumpiness.

Your best bet for smooth scrolling is to use items of the same height or not use virtualisation.

Comment: But what about an app like face book. The user controls will be of different heights (one with just normal text post and other when there is a image or video shared.)

Comment: @Prakash and yes, they spent a long time getting the perf right with varying height items. (Can't say how I know ;) )

Comment: That is fine. But can I have any other suggestions on making the feel better than making the user controls of same height. Because I have the same scenario of facebook. Any reference would be greatly appreciated. :) Thanks.

Comment: And what will happen if I stop using binding and create the controls in memory add to the list dynamically. Will that make a difference. I am going to test that. Just informing you so that I may get some suggestions.