# Reduce number of items that LongListSelector creates on startup

Tags: performance, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I know that `LongListSelector` does UI virtualization, that is it creates a number of items sufficient to fill the screen plus a few more beyound that and then as user scolls content `LongListSelector` recycles them instead of creating new ones.

In my case 6 items are enough to fill the screen and after some research I've found out that `LongListSelector` loads 20-22 items on startup. I think this can be safelly reduced to 10 items or so. The question is, can the number of initially created items be reduced somehow?

Comment: Are you having performance problems? the `LongListSelector` is optimised, and unless your `ItemTemplate` is very complex, I don't see the default UI virtualisation as a concern.

Comment: In a way, yes. I have some UserControls that are being created and added to the scene dynamically that contain LongListSelector inside and there's very small but sometimes noticeable glitch when LongListSelector loads items at the first time.

Comment: I don't see anything of help in the docs for [`LongListSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector(v=vs.105).aspx). I did find a couple of related posts dealing with [scrolling performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9467419/how-to-attain-virtualization-in-listbox-with-different-layouts-of-windows-phone) and [data virtualisation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441510/listbox-data-virtualization-is-not-taking-effect).

Comment: Data virtualization might be the answer I guess but I basically use an `ObservableCollection` with it's data binding capabilities such as `Add` and `Remove`, not an `IList` class. Are there any ways of combining them to get advanced binding support and data virtualization?

Comment: For a custom `ObservableCollection`, you could use [Caliburn.Micro's `BindableCollection` as a reference](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9df8a18b6be4#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/INPC.cs). The only other suggestion I have, and it's a bit crazy, is to take the WP7 version of the `LongListSelector` from the WP Toolkit, rename then customise it - I might make an answer from all these suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector(v=vs.105).aspx), there doesn't seem to be any method or property that would allow to customise the amount of UI virtualisation the `LongListSelector` does by default.

You could look into data virtualisation. [Previous  answers/tutorials use an `IList`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441510/listbox-data-virtualization-is-not-taking-effect), but it shouldn't be too much work to use [a modified `ObservableCollection` instead](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/9df8a18b6be4#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/INPC.cs).

Another idea, which I haven't tried, is to take the [WP7 version of `LongListSelector`](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336037) from the WP Toolkit, rename then customise it. But that might be a lot of work.